# does python have any service like jndi?

Tags: python, service, jndi

I wanted to know if python had any service like Java's JNDI.

More specifically, I want a service where providers can register themselves and then consumers can ask fro where certain provider end-points are.

For example, assume that I want to implement a mailbox for all my friends. Each of them have their own end-point, so friend1, friend2, friend3 each have their own end point. Furthermore, each end-point can change over time, so if initially, we start off with:

```
friend1 -> end-point1
friend2 -> end-point2
friend3 -> end-point3
```

We may, after some point have:

```
friend1 -> end-point1
friend2 -> end-point3
friend3 -> end-point4
```

The serice discovery daemon should willing to accomodate these dynamic changes in the system.

Comment: This is something that could be handled by a simple lookup on a database, a dictionary var sitting in some `module.py`, or even a DNS service. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Amplifying Camilo, what do you want to lookup? JNDI - or any Python re-write - is very heavyweight and is likely overkill for most applications. (Actually that goes for most java packages for reasons of broad applicability and standards compliance).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the exact equivalent, but you can read [this study](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonAndJ2EE) to get an overview of what available. Remember you can always use Jython if you feel like using Python and Java tech together.

In the end, I tend to agree with @msw, JNDI is probably overkill.